# How do I change the code below to add two rows?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I change the code below to add 2 rows?

```
Sub AddRows()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim iCounter As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Numbers")
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set MyRange = Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

        For iCounter = MyRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1

            'Insert blank row,
            MyRange.Rows(iCounter).EntireRow.Insert

        Next iCounter
    End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: **Add** two rows or **insert** two rows ??

Comment: @Gary's Student Sorry that should be insert two rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are intending to *insert* two rows (see Gary's comment), the you can make a quick change from this:

```
MyRange.Rows(iCounter).EntireRow.Insert
```

To

```
MyRange.Rows(iCounter).Resize(2,1).EntireRow.Insert
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly.